# Get last location of multiple users?

Tags: cassandra

Users are always sending their location (long, lat) to Cassandra to store their location into a time series table.

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    organization_id int,
    user_id int,
    date text,
    unix_time bigint,
    lat double,
    long double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((organization_id, user_id, date), unix_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (unix_time DESC);
```

What's the advice when it comes to retrieve the last location of multiple users?

As I will be using `LIMIT` as something like that:

```
SELECT * from myapp.locations WHERE organization_id=1 and user_id in (15,16, 17, 18, 19, 20)  and date='2017-2-23' LIMIT 6;
```

What if last 6 records belongs to the same user? thus, won't get last locations of other users..

Shall create another table that keeps only one location of each user? and keep updating location of each user in it?

What's the advice here?

Comment: Which programming language are you using ? java ?

Comment: Elixir, based on Erlang

Comment: Is there any executeAsync to execute query in  Elixir ?

Comment: Sure, Elixir can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should query for each user with executeAsync, and then merge the result.**

For every user use this query to get his latest location :

```
SELECT * from myapp.locations WHERE organization_id=1 and date='2017-2-23' and user_id = ? LIMIT 1
```

and execute this using executeAsync, and then merge the result

If you make separate table, you need to partition it by userid, then you need to make in query with userids, which is slower, for faster you have to make separate query with executeAsync for each user on this table also.

Also there is another thing location will update more frequently, So every update cassandra will need to do more work on compaction, can slow down your performance

Comment: So, do you think this is better than having another table that have locations updated?

Comment: thanks for answer, I will show you elixir code when its done :)

Comment: But, what about cases that we need to do frequent updates?

Comment: In Cassandra update and insert both are upsert so if you use separate table, your upserting rate will be double.

Comment: It seems that I will have to create another table that does not rely on `date` as a part of the primary key, as I have to get last locations without specifying the `date` in query due to the api name, which should get the last location without specifying date, what do you think?

Comment: If you can't specify the date, it's good idea to create another table